# seq -f option uses a C printf floating point format?

Tags: command-line, seq

The `seq` man page explains the `-f` option like this.

```
-f, --format=FORMAT
             use printf style floating-point FORMAT
```

Here is an example.

```
$ seq -f 'logfile%02g.txt' 3
logfile01.txt
logfile02.txt
logfile03.txt
```

I know what it can do. However I'm not sure about the "`printf` style floating-point FORMAT". What are `%02g` and `3` for??

Comment: `man printf`...

Comment: `man 3 printf` is more informative about the format specifiers iirc

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` option uses the format of the `printf` internal bash command as shown by the following excerpt from the results of `seq --help` :

```
$ seq --help
Usage: seq [OPTION]... LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
  or:  seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
Print numbers from FIRST to LAST, in steps of INCREMENT.

  -f, --format=FORMAT      use printf style floating-point FORMAT
```

`%02g` uses the format of the `printf` internal bash command. The `%02g` stands for use the output format: `%g` (which is the default) but with a `0` in front of the number. The leading `0` is used as padding only if necessary for printing lines 1-9 of the sequence. No `0` padding is necessary for printing lines 10-99 of the sequence.

The 2 stands for the minimum "character size" of the number which is 2 characters in this example. If the sequence is long enough, more than the minimum character size of the number will be printed which starts at the minimum character size of two characters and adjusts automatically in length if necessary as the printed sequence increments. If `%02g` is replaced by `%03g` then a minimum of three numbers are printed. If `%02g` is replaced by `%01g` then the leading `0` padding for lines 1-9 is omitted and a minimum of one number is printed.

The 3 at the end of `seq -f 'logfile%02g.txt' 3` is the length of the sequence that will be printed.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: What part of the answer didn't you understand? Is it the part about using a **zero for padding** before the sequence number in order for it to  reach its minimum length? Or is it the part about the **size** of a sequence number expands automatically to fit the **length** of the sequence number?

Comment: I'm trying to get more examples. I'll get back to your answer later.